# DirectoryIndex .htaccess directive is being overridden by RewriteRules

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, oxwall

I have the following .htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

AddEncoding gzip .gz
AddEncoding gzip .gzip
<FilesMatch "\.(js.gz|js.gzip)$">
  ForceType text/javascript
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(css.gz|css.gzip)$">
  ForceType text/css
</FilesMatch>

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*/http-bind
#RewriteRule (.*) /http-bind [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ow_updates/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ow_updates/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ow_cron/run\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index\.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.xml|\.feed|robots\.txt|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
```

I want everything else in the .htaccess to work like it was: redirect all requests except those specified with `!` to `index.php`. However, I need to load `index.html` the first time the site is loaded, and them keep loading `index.php` afterwards.

So I added the line `DirectoryIndex index.html` at the beginning, and then added the line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index\.html`, hoping that when users type `http://url.com`, they are taken to the index.html file, from which they will go to inner pages like `http://url.com/homepage` which will all be requests handled by `index.php`.

This is not working, however. The software I am using is [Oxwall](http://www.oxwall.org/). The site simply ignores the first line and keeps loading index.php no matter what. What can I do to remedy this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily handle this with PHP with either the session or cookies. You can make it always redirect somebody to index.php and in index.php you can include the index.html file to show if they are visiting the first time. If you redirect them to the html file it will not work (.htaccess will get in the way), but if you include the file then it should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks; yes, this is indeed a possibility, but I'd like to avoid it because there is already a lot of cookie/session manipulation in the main site script and I'd be interfering in that logic...